# Is it possible to use an instance method as a callable for scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Is it possible to use an instance method as a callable function in SciPy, for example with scipy.optimize.minimize?

I have a few variants of a state-space model that are defined in different classes all derived from a parent "KalmanFilterModel" class. Each subclass defines its own filter() instance method (KalmanFilterModel as well, but no shown here).

What I'm trying to do is write an instance method that estimates the parameters of the model by maximum likelihood.

Here is a snippet of the code I have:

```
class KalmanFilterModel:
    def estimate_parameters(self, obs, x0=None):

        self._obs = obs

        if x0 is None:
            x0 = np.array([0.5, 0.7, 1.0])

        result = minimize(fun=self._minimization, x0=x0,
                          options={'maxiter': 300})

        return result

    def _minimization(self, x):
        # Function to minimize when estimating parameters.
        self.eta = x[0]
        self.mu = x[1]
        self.inverse_beta = x[2]


        return -self.filter(self._obs)
```

However, when I try to run it I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'set' and 'float'
```

Is it possible at all to use an instance method in this case, and if so what's the best way of doing it?

Comment: It should work just fine. You probably have some other bug. Make sure all the function signatures match what they're supposed to, and look for the part where you're trying to divide a set by a float.

Comment: You're right, it was a stupid typo on my part when I changed the return type of the `filter` function from dict to float I left the `{}` around the float variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

```
In [4]: class F(object):
   ...:     def meth(self, x):
   ...:         return (x-1.)**2
   ...:     

In [5]: ff = F()

In [6]: minimize(ff.meth, 2.)
Out[6]: 
   status: 0
  success: True
     njev: 3
     nfev: 9
 hess_inv: array([[1]])
      fun: 1.3877787807814457e-17
        x: array([ 1.])
  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
      jac: array([  2.23517418e-08])
```